# Android - RecyclerView: Add new item and select it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in a fragment and the items are selectable. I solved that with creating a variable `int focusedItem = 0;` in the RvAdapter and `holder.itemView.setSelected(focusedItem == position);` in the onBindViewHolder method. And this is the onClick method of an item:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        notifyItemChanged(focusedItem);
        focusedItem = position;
        notifyItemChanged(focusedItem);
    }
});
```

And in the XML file for the list item I used a selector as the background, which changes the background color of the selected item. This is working fine, but I want to add items to the recycler view and after adding an item it is not working so good anymore.

This is how I add an item to the rv (in the fragment class):

```
entries.add(0, new ...);
rvAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```

So I add an item to the ArrayList on the first position. Then I notify the adapter, that a new item on the first position is inserted and then I scroll to that new item. Now I want that the new item is automatically selected. Is there any way to do that? My idea was to set the `focusedItem = 0` but I dont know how to edit this value in the fragment class. Or is there something like onItemInserted where I can set this variable to 0?

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `notify..` set `focusedItem` to 0. `onBindViewHolder` will be called later resulting in item being displayed as selected.

```
entries.add(0, new ...);
focusedItem = 0;
rvAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```

EDIT:

So you defined `focusedItem` in your `Fragment` instead of `Adapter`? It will be better to just move it to `Adapter` and add getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

@Roman Kolomenskii had the idea to place the `focusedItem` variable in the fragment class and not in the RvAdapter class. That was a good idea and its working.

So in my Fragment class I have `public static int focusedItem = 0;` and here is the code when I add an item:

```
int oldFocusedItem = focusedItem;
focusedItem = 0;
rvAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
rvAdapter.notifyItemChanged(oldFocusedItem+1);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```

I have to store the latest selectedItem because I must notify the adapter, that this item + 1 (because there is a new item before) got changed, because it must loose the selection. And then I set the focusedItem to 0. And in the RvAdapter class I use `MyFragment.focusedItem` to get the selected item.